# A Tricky Weak Derivatives question

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functional-analysis, derivatives

I recently came across the following statement and am having trouble proving it correct. I wonder if you could help.

Given a weak derivative, $x'$, there exists an absolutely continuous representative of $x$ (which we shall still call $x$, for convenience), such that
$x(b)-x(a)= \int_{a}^{b}x'(v)\mathrm{d}v$, $\forall a,b \in\Bbb R^{+}$.
Please, this has me somewhat stumped.

Comment: Maybe somewhat related to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/690407/weak-derivative-questions), which has, sadly, not received much attention.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Characterisation of one-dimensional Sobolev space](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/903881/characterisation-of-one-dimensional-sobolev-space)

Comment: Please be precise about your particular definition of 'weak derivative.'

Comment: Indeed, so it seems, that it is a repeat as Tomas cited. Forgive my ignorance, but is there any snags as we are dealing with the representative (?); possibly not. Thank you Tomas.

Comment: Given, I am new to this subject (but wish to learn), perhaps Tomas night be kind enough to comment which Lemma/Thm he used (from Brezis presumably) to generate his solution in the link. Thank you

Comment: Dear MrNemo, when you want talk to someone in particular, you have to write @nickname, so the guy will be notified. Now, concerning your request, could you be more specific please? Is this related with your last question that I alread answered?